# textfiled:Charactersinrange method not returning appropriate output

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

If under `-(void)textField:charactersInrange` method I am writing:

```
if([textField.text length]>6)
{
    return NO;

}
else
    return YES;
```

then in result it takes 7 outputs instead of 6.

Now if I do

```
if([textField.text length]>=6)
{
    return NO;
}
```

For the 1st time its taking 6 letters but if u cancel it and giving input second time then 5 letters taking. How to solve this problem ? Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: i mean 7 letters/numbers from keyboard

Comment: Please clarify what method you are talking about.  I don't see that method on the `UITextFieldDelegate` reference.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict user input to 6 characters, then try [textField.text length]>=6

Comment: Please don't hesitate to edit your question in order to clarify things, instead of doing it in the comments. That way everyone will see it.

Comment: Now if i do 
if([textField.text length]>=6)
    {
        return NO;
}
 for the 1st time its taking 6 letters but if u cancel it and giving input second time then 5 letters taking . How to solve this problem ? Please Help.`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this piece of code:

```
if([textField.text length]>=6){
   return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: have done this too... but the thing is that for the 1st time its taking 6 letters but if u cancel it and giving input second time then 5 letters taking . How to solve this problem ?

Comment: btw such statements can be written in this way `return !([textField.text length]>=6);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (textField.text.length >= 6){ // that means, if the textfield's text's length is greater OR equal to 6.
   return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
```

Now, how can it "take" 7 outputs?  "takes 7 outputs instead of 6."